# slideTo(1) is working but slideTo(0) is not working with swiper js using ionic 7 + Angular

Tags: angular, ionic7

Below is working

```
<swiper-container id="swiper" (transitionstart)="slideTransitionStart()" #swiper>
            <swiper-slide *ngFor="let image of bannerList">
                <img [src]="image.picturePath | sanitizer" />
            </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>

slideTransitionStart() {
        const mySwiper = new Swiper('#swiper');
        mySwiper.slideTo(1);
}
```

Below is not working

```
<swiper-container id="swiper" (transitionstart)="slideTransitionStart()" #swiper>
            <swiper-slide *ngFor="let image of bannerList">
                <img [src]="image.picturePath | sanitizer" />
            </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>

slideTransitionStart() {
        const mySwiper = new Swiper('#swiper');
        mySwiper.slideTo(0);
}
```

When I am on the second slide and try to swipe the slide using `mySwiper.slideTo(1)`, It stays in the same slide and that is what I expect but when I am on the first slide and try to swipe the slide using `mySwiper.slideTo(0)`, It does not stay on the same slide and move to the next slide. So it needs to be on the same slide.